# positioning of tables in a big file

Tags: tables, positioning

I have a strange problem when positioning table in a big file. I use the option `h!` to put the table exactly where the code is written.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
...
\end{table}
```

The problem is, in the big file, I have 4 table, at different places 'supposodely' separated by pages (with a lot of text in between). At the end, all the tables are regrouped at the end of the chapter, sometimes 5 pages after their supposed placement!  This bothers me very much, and I don't understand why. With figure the option h! comes in handy, the figure is always placed as close as possible from the point where I put it... Does it not work in the same way with tables?

Thank you very much.
Claude.

Comment: Urban myth: `h!`  puts the graphic/table *exactly here*. It is just a myth, `h!` does not place the graphic/table *exactly here*.

Comment: so is there an alternative to the problem?????????.  My problem is that in my long chapter I have figures as well, and with figures it works perfectly ( meaning, it always put the figure as closely as possible from the point where I insert it......), why did it work with figures and not with tables??

Comment: [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)

Comment: The option [!htbp] seems to be useless

Comment: Stefans answer says, it is *often* sufficient. And later: "`float` introduces a placement option `H` **enforcing** the placement exactly at that point."

Comment: Thanks, float package with option H seems to give a satisfactory result! Thank you for your answer!